# How to define schematron in xml file to validate?

Tags: php, xml, eclipse, validation, schema

I'm newbie in XML stuffs. Answer would be simple but am struggling for couple of days. Ofcourse was fully in stackoverflow to get the solution but I don't know whether I have enough knowledge in XML to get it or understand it. So, finally am here to get the solution from experts.

Well, I have an xml file, DTD and sch file. Am using eclipse to validate an xml against DTD. But i don't know how to validate an xml against sch file.

**Sample xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE SAGE-hubxml
  PUBLIC "-//SAGE//DTD SAGE Hub XML DTD v1.0 20111101/EN" "SAGE-hubxml.dtd">
<SAGE-hubxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<body>
</body>
</SAGE-hubxml>
```

In this, I have defined DTD file to validate. I don't know how to define sch file to validate. What would be the simplest way to do it?
And I would use php to validate an xml against DTD.

**php**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->Load('sample.xml');
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
}
else{
echo "This document is not  valid!";
}
```

So, if we can validate xml against sch using php, would be greatly helpful

**Updates**

In some documentation, they have mentioned about oxygen xml editor,to validate against sch file. I need something else similar as oxygen is a commerical tool.
[image: /home/srini/Pictures/Selection_003.png]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can define a schematron file like a XML schema (or DTD) and validate it the same way.

You have to use a php schematron library than can process sch files, or transform the sch files into XSLT files, then an XLST processor to validate the XML file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated my post. Pls have a look at it.  And the suggestion which you said is the only solution for my requirement?

Comment: If you want to do it with php, then I can't help you more :( Using java you have http://www.probatron.org/ . You can also check official site : http://www.schematron.com/resources.html

Comment: Using command line `java -jar probatron.jar document-to-validate schematron-schema` we can validate it seems. But they have mentioned `document-to-validate schematron-schema` so the input file is sch or xml here?

Comment: `document-to-validate` : the xml file to validate
`schematron-schema` : the schematron file containing rules

Comment: So, input is xml file to be validated. And where to define sch file.. In xml file or in command line?

Comment: The sch file is a XML file containing rules, you can find example and explanation in links provided

Comment: sorry!. Is that two inputs in command line  like `java -jar probatron.jar sample.xml sample.sch`?

Comment: Actually I need to validate my xml file against sch file.. like xml file against DTD

Comment: sample.sch is the Schematron schema containing the rules for validation (like a DTD).

Comment: That's wat,  how to validate xml file against schematron schema